# Why is the top of stack the first value loaded from the vector table after reset?

Tags: c, keil

The following has a priority higher than `reset_handler`.

Why do such a thing?

I know that the datasheet of any ARM-based MCU forces that order by hardware, but why it is the highest priority?

```
__Vectors   DCD     __initial_sp               ; Top of Stack
            DCD     Reset_Handler              ; Reset Handler
            DCD     NMI_Handler                ; NMI Handler
            DCD     HardFault_Handler          ; Hard Fault Handler
            DCD     MemManage_Handler          ; MPU Fault Handler
            DCD     BusFault_Handler           ; Bus Fault Handler
            DCD     UsageFault_Handler         ; Usage Fault Handler
            DCD     0                          ; Reserved
            DCD     0                          ; Reserved
            DCD     0                          ; Reserved
            DCD     0                          ; Reserved
            DCD     SVC_Handler                ; SVCall Handler
            DCD     DebugMon_Handler           ; Debug Monitor Handler
            DCD     0                          ; Reserved
            DCD     PendSV_Handler             ; PendSV Handler
            DCD     SysTick_Handler            ; SysTick Handler
```

Comment: It is not highest priority, and it is not a vector. It is the architecture convention to have the initial SP there.

Comment: It is because the engineer  who has designed the core decided to have SP there. It could be anywhere, but it is there. Stack pointer does not have the priority. But probably it is because the first operation before jumping anywhere has to be stack pointer initialization.

Comment: Aside: some processors inhibit the non-maskable interrupt until the stack pointer has been initialised. The reset vector is hard coded into the processor for a power-on reset and it is often the programmer's responsibility to initialise a stack pointer. Without that exception to "non-maskable" it may not be possible to initialise the I/O systems.